# Use LUKS and LVM on install to external drive

Tags: 12.10, lvm, ubiquity, luks

So I have a laptop running Backtrack 5 R3 using LUKS and LVM, manually configured, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 to a USB 3 external drive and use LUKS and LVM on that as well, but I can't seem to get the automated installer to default to my external drive instead of trying to overwrite my BT5 installation, and while it gives me the option to install alongside it, I'd prefer to just install to the external drive for portability without having to do the fancy LUKS and LVM manual config I had to do with the internal BT installation, plus I don't know if the installer would realize it's an unlocked LUKS container and not try to unmount it if I tried to do automated side-by-side installation on the internal drive. Do I have to just remove the internal disk so it won't recognize it during installation?

Thanks,
Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set up a virtual machine which has it's CD pointing to the ubuntu install iso, and your pen drive mapped as the hard disk store... At least your internal hard drives can be disconnected in the virtual environment, and it stands a chance of working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's actually not a bad idea! I ended up taking out my internal SSD and Ubiquity defaulted to the external (of course). If I had to do it again, I'd probably go with your idea or just do it manually like I did with BackTrack on the internal. Also, just a heads up to anyone reading this in the future, it creates an unencrypted swap partition for the automated install, arguably devaluing the encryption if you ever run out of RAM. I'm not using this for high-sec work like with BT, but if you are, you should probably do a manual config with cryptsetup.